# network admin in user panel add filter option

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

Hi Team I am new to WordPress, just want to add a new filter option in the multisite WordPress network, in the all-user panel just want to add some filter options[image: rd].

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of a hacky answer for you:

```
<?php

/**
 *  Allowing Network Administrators to Export All Users
 */

function __add_export_network_users_button( )
{
    if ( !is_network_admin( ) )
        return;

    $screen = get_current_screen( );

    if ( $screen->id != "users-network" )
        return;

    var_dump( $screen );
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($)
        {
            $('.tablenav.top .clear, .tablenav.bottom .clear').before('<form action="#" method="POST"><input type="hidden" id="mysite_download_all_users" name="mysite_download_all_users" value="1" /><input class="button button-primary user_export_button" type="submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Export All Users' );?>" /></form>');
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

function __export_network_users( )
{
    global $wpdb;

    if ( !is_network_admin( ) )
        return;

    if ( !empty( $_POST['mysite_download_all_users'] ) )
    {
        if ( current_user_can('manage_options') )
        {
            header("Content-type: application/force-download");
            header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="wp-users-'.date('YmdHis').'.csv"');

            $sql = "SELECT
                    ID,
                    user_login,
                    user_email,
                    CASE
                        WHEN domain IS NULL THEN 'SUPER ADMIN'
                        ELSE domain
                    END AS \"site_domain\",
                    UPPER( REPLACE( SUBSTR( meta_value, 12 ), '\";b:1;}', '' ) ) AS \"Role\",
                    last_updated
                FROM
                    wp_usermeta
                LEFT JOIN
                    wp_users
                        ON user_id = wp_users.ID
                LEFT JOIN
                    wp_blogs
                        ON wp_blogs.blog_id = REPLACE( REPLACE( meta_key, '_capabilities', '' ), 'wp_', '' )
                WHERE
                    meta_key LIKE '%_capabilities'
                ORDER BY
                    user_id ASC;";

            $results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, 'ARRAY_A' );

            if ( is_array( $results ) && 0 < count( $results ) )
            {
                echo implode( ',', array_keys( $results[0] ) ).PHP_EOL;

                foreach ( $results as $result )
                    echo implode( ',', array_values( $result ) ).PHP_EOL;

                exit( 0 );
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_footer', '__add_export_network_users_button' );
add_action( 'admin_init', '__export_network_users' );
```

Classic Wordpress - there's actions and filters, until there isn't.

Comment: Hi, while your answer may address the question, it's better to include some [explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers)